# Yii redirect error

Tags: php, yii

I have redirect system to redirect old urls to new urls.

I write my code actionError in site controller (*that is good or not ?*).. it's work locally (widnows) but it's not work live (linux)... error msg in chrome is : Oops! This link appears to be broken.

**my code:**
http://pastebin.com/nSJH5dwX

I think the problem is load geoiploc.php and this is too big file... what do you think ?

Comment: What do you mean by "you think the problem is gepiploc.php" have you tried firebug or google developer tools in chrome to see what the browser is trying to load and how long that is taking?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that if it works on Windows very good but not on linux is due to the letter case in the filename, please be sure that `include("geoiploc.php");` has the same letter case than **geoiploc.php file** . Linux won't find the file if it has a different letter case like: **geoIpLoc.php**, or **Geoiploc.php**